# Function of $.getJSON

Tags: jquery, json

I want to know what `$.getJSON` exactly does.

Is it used to send a request?
OR
Is it used as a callback function?

Also, please let me know the various scenarios wherein I can use `$.getJSON`

Answer (score 1):

`$.getJSON` makes an ajax request to the specified url with the specified data. You specify a calback when you want to use the results of the ajax request like so:

```
 $.getJSON('SomeUrl\Path\On\Your\Server', 
      { someProperty: 'someValue' },
       function(response)
       {
          // Do Stuff with the response
       });
```

You'd want to use `$.getJSON` when you want to make a JSON get request. It sounds like you haven't read the documentation though - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Answer (score 1):

Here's the entry for the [jQuery $.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) with a nice explanation and examples.

Essentially, $.getJSON() sends an asynchronous GET request to a specified URL and treat the response data as JSON, converting it to an object. Because request is asynchronous, response will not come at once; therefore you do not get the data back immediately but provide a callback which will be called and passed the interpreted JSON data as an argument once the response comes back from the server.

High level scenario for this method is when you may have an extended or updated content on your server you want to load later or as a result of user interaction and you want to receive the data to use later in the script rather than HTML.